# React-router-dom V5 to v6 upgrade multiple Errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  Route,
  RouteComponentProps,
  RouteProps,
  useLocation,
  useMatch
} from 'react-router-dom';
import AuthenticationContext from './AuthenticationContext';

/* eslint-disable react/jsx-props-no-spreading */
function PrivateRoute(routeProps: RouteProps) {
  const {
    children,
    component: Component,
    ...routePropsWithoutChildrenAndComponent
  } = routeProps;

  const { authorize, authenticated, authenticating, callbackPath } =
    useContext(AuthenticationContext);
  const location = useLocation();
  const match = useMatch(routePropsWithoutChildrenAndComponent);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!authenticated
      && !authenticating
      && match
      && location.pathname !== callbackPath
    ) {
      authorize(location as unknown as URL);
    }
  }, [
    authorize,
    match,
    location,
    authenticated,
    authenticating,
    callbackPath
  ]);

  return (
    <Route
      {...routePropsWithoutChildrenAndComponent}
      render={(props: RouteComponentProps) => {
        if (!authenticated) return null;
        if (Component) return <Component {...props} />;
        // eslint-disable-next-line react/destructuring-assignment
        if (routeProps.render) return routeProps.render(props);
        return children as React.ReactNode;
      }}
    />
  );
}

PrivateRoute.propTypes = (Route as unknown as React.ComponentClass).propTypes;

export default PrivateRoute;
```

After upgrading `react-router-dom` v5 to v6 and `@types/react-router-dom` to v5.3.3 facing multiple errors:

```
packages/auth/src/PrivateRoute.tsx:2:17 - error TS2305: Module '"react-router-dom"' has no exported member 'RouteComponentProps'.

2 import { Route, RouteComponentProps, RouteProps, useLocation, useMatch } from 'react-router-dom';
                  ~~~~~~~

packages/auth/src/PrivateRoute.tsx:8:21 - error TS2339: Property 'component' does not exist on type 'RouteProps'.

8   const { children, component: Component, ...routePropsWithoutChildrenAndComponent } = routeProps;
                      ~~~

packages/auth/src/PrivateRoute.tsx:12:26 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ caseSensitive?: boolean | undefined; path?: string | undefined; id?: string | undefined; lazy?: LazyRouteFunction<NonIndexRouteObject> | undefined; ... 11 more ...; ErrorBoundary?: ComponentType<...> | ... 1 more ... | undefined; } | { ...; } | { ...; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | PathPattern<string>'.
  Type '{ caseSensitive?: boolean | undefined; path?: string | undefined; id?: string | undefined; lazy?: LazyRouteFunction<NonIndexRouteObject> | undefined; ... 11 more ...; ErrorBoundary?: ComponentType<...> | ... 1 more ... | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'string | PathPattern<string>'.
    Type '{ caseSensitive?: boolean | undefined; path?: string | undefined; id?: string | undefined; lazy?: LazyRouteFunction<NonIndexRouteObject> | undefined; ... 11 more ...; ErrorBoundary?: ComponentType<...> | ... 1 more ... | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'PathPattern<string>'.
      Types of property 'path' are incompatible.
        Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
          Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

12   const match = useMatch(routePropsWithoutChildrenAndComponent);
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

packages/auth/src/PrivateRoute.tsx:23:7 - error TS2322: Type '{ render: (props: RouteComponentProps) => any; caseSensitive?: boolean | undefined; path?: string | undefined; id?: string | undefined; lazy?: LazyRouteFunction<NonIndexRouteObject> | undefined; ... 11 more ...; ErrorBoundary?: ComponentType<...> | ... 1 more ... | undefined; } | { ...; } | { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RouteProps'.
  Type '{ render: (props: RouteComponentProps) => any; caseSensitive?: boolean | undefined; path?: string | undefined; id?: string | undefined; lazy?: LazyRouteFunction<NonIndexRouteObject> | undefined; ... 11 more ...; ErrorBoundary?: ComponentType<...> | ... 1 more ... | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RouteProps'.
    Property 'render' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PathRouteProps'.

23       render={(props: RouteComponentProps) => {
         ~~

packages/auth/src/PrivateRoute.tsx:27:24 - error TS2339: Property 'render' does not exist on type 'RouteProps'.
  Property 'render' does not exist on type 'PathRouteProps'.

27         if (routeProps.render) return routeProps.render(props);
                          ~~

packages/auth/src/PrivateRoute.tsx:27:50 - error TS2339: Property 'render' does not exist on type 'RouteProps'.
  Property 'render' does not exist on type 'PathRouteProps'.

27         if (routeProps.render) return routeProps.render(props);
                                                    ~~
```

Comment: React-Router-DOM (RRD) v6 is written in Typescript, there is no `@types/react-router-dom` package for it, and in fact, any that you are using should be removed from the project to not cause type conflicts. The RRD component APIs also significantly changed, we don't render [`Route`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route) component directly and it uses completely different props. The [useMatch](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-match) also takes a path patten argument, not a "props" argument. It's not clear why you need a `match` variable here though.